# How to externalize string using Typescript [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on an Angular project. I've created a custom `month-picker` component. Everything is working absolutely fine. But now my senior told me to make all the month names external because we may switch to Russian or French language later. So I'm now reading month names from an external json file **assets/i18n/en-US.json**. I'm using `TranslateService`. I've setup everything here: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/translate-nick-13-kc2pui). Please let me know what's the problem. And one more thing, if I hardcode my month array as:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 ...
 this.months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', ..., 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
 ...
}
```

Then it works great. But not when i externalize them. Please help.

Comment: Where are you trying to *internationalize* strings? You aren't using the translate pipe anywhere. ++ Way too much code in your stackblitz. Can you clean it up to include only the *relevant* code related to the question?

Comment: Hi Nicholas. Good to see you. I forked one of your project. I'm doing it in **monthpicker.component.ts**

Comment: But i dont want to use pipe. Is there anyway to do it using pipe. Because HTML file isn't in my control. Someone else is writing it.

Comment: Yeah you can. But there is just too much code. What exactly are you trying to do? Please edit your question to explain the same.

Comment: ok. give me some time.

Comment: try to initialize inside `this.translateModes((data)=>{`

Comment: I mean your `initRangeState` method is called before translate done. So `this.months` is empty

Comment: @NicholasK. Done Sir. Please check now.

Comment: @yogendarji. thats why i'm using call back. will try your solutions anyway. thanks

Comment: @yogendarji. `initRangeState` is a different thing. In fact in the updated code that method is not even there. Its totally unrelated.

Comment: `this.translateModes((data)=>{
  this.initMonthsDataState();
        });` something like this

Comment: @yogendarji. Please post this as an answer and explain if possible. So that I can accept. This worked. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205203/discussion-between-tanzeel-and-yogen-darji).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only bug in your code is you calling `this.initMonthsDataState()` method fore `translateModes` finish and setting months name so simple solution would be

```
this.translateModes((data)=>{
 this.initMonthsDataState();
});
```

But I will suggest to add `translate` pipe directly into HTML as below

```
// Initialize months with translate directly and use it in HTML

<div>{{ x.monthName | translate }}</div>

months=[
       'Monthpicker.Months.January',
        'Monthpicker.Months.February',...]


initMonthsDataState() {
    this.monthsData = new Array();
    this.years.forEach(year => {
        this.months.forEach(month => {
            this.monthsData.push({
                monthName: month,
                monthYear: year,
                isInRange: false,
                isLowerEdge: false,
                isUpperEdge: false
            });
        });
    });
```

[fiddle to above logic](https://stackblitz.com/edit/translate-nick-13-hj9ijg)

Comment: On console: 
ERROR TypeError: "_co.monthsData is undefined"